# User class and form update PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have created this form to update the data of the various user profiles. The update works but I would need some tricks and aid. The form is really minimal, reduced to essentials, **I was wondering how to improve it, perhaps placing the controls to make it as safe as possible, how can I do?**

Also, I can not take the id of the user via the SESSION, other data picks them up, as a location, but the email ID no. So I'll need just because the form has to be based of course the ID of the user. **I was wondering if invede of SESSIONS, it was not better to create a class that collects user data**, for example: $user['email'];

However, I paste the class user.php

```
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){  
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            return true;
        }       
    }

    public function is_logged_admin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['level']) && $_SESSION['level'] == 2 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }  

    public function get_user_info($username){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT memberID,email,location,gender,level,active FROM members WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($username));
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

}
```

and the form that I called account.php

```
<form role="form" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">      
<label class="control-label">Email</label>     
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?= $_SESSION['email']; ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Location</label>           
<input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" value="<?= $_SESSION['location']; ?>">   
</div>

<div class="form-group">       
<label class="control-label">Gender</label>   
<input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" value="<?= $_SESSION['gender']; ?>">    
</div>

<div class="margiv-top-10">  
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Update">    
</div>

</form>
```

And,

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET email = ?, location = ?, gender = ? WHERE memberID = 1");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender']]);
}
```

Comment: How do the results of `function get_user_info($username)` get into your `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Yes, but when I update the data on the page account.php the new data is not shown immediately, but only after a while. I was looking for an alternative, updating the data were shown immediately changes. How can I do?

Comment: Add more details to your post. How is FORM posted to account.php. What is the code in account.php? What is the expected result?

Comment: I have written and specified what is the code inside account.php, would be the last two codes. How can I improve the code by adding the controls? Also, wondering if you could help me in creating a class where you handle the data of each respective user, avoiding SESSION

Comment: Based on the info you have posted, I am not able to do that. You could perform similar activities by storing session data in a database versus in memory. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: I would not start a new topic, I'm just wondering if you know how to put messages of success or failure, the syntax I definitely mistaken. I know help on this? thanks